# Not able to run erlang rabbit mq examples

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

I downloaded the complete Rabitmq examples and tried to run it according to the instructions in this link https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-tutorials/tree/master/erlang. But when trying to run ./send the following error occurs.

> ./send.erl:4: can't find includelib"amqp_client/include/amqp_client.hrl"
>
> escript: There were compilation errors.

I have followed the instructions carefully ..What should I do now?

Comment: Did you download the erlang amqp client?